# How to hide a radio button in angular material 6

Tags: radio-button, radio-group, angular-material-6

Want to hide a default selected radio button on my angular web application in a reactive form so that it is not visible to the customers but i could pass that value to the request to my http call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intent is for the user to never see this radio button, do not add it to the html/view... simply store the value in a `formControl` and call the value from the `formControl` when you make your http call.

```
this.yourForm = new FormGroup({
    radioButton: new FormControl(DefaultValueHere)
})
```

Then in your http call

```
this.yourForm.get('radioButton').value
```

There is no need to pass it to the view only to hide it, just keep it in the `formControl` and use it when you need it.